# R Network Graph in Shiny not working

Tags: r, shiny, igraph

I'm trying to display different graphs based on a dropdown input from a user.  I have the other inputs working.  It's just the network graph that isn't working.  If I switch it to a different graph, it works; it's just the network graph that isn't working.

```
    if(input$level == "function"){

  data = matrix(sample(0:1, 400, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8,0.2)), nrow = 20)
  network = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(data, mode='undirected', diag = F)

  plot(network, layout = layout.circle, main = "circle")
}
```

it's all within a reactive function.  I have also tried using the igraph library, as well as the igraphinshiny library

Comment: Can you please include more of your code? I.e., could you actually include a runnable app, where the network plot fails, but others work fine?

Answer (score 1):

The following example plots Network graph or a simple plot of 5 points depending of selected choice:

```
library(shiny)
library(igraph)
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("graph", 
                  label = "Choose graph to display",
                  choices = c("Simple plot", "Network Graph"), 
                  selected = "Network Graph")), 
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myplot")
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$myplot <- renderPlot({

    # Plot Network graph is selected
    if (input$graph == "Network Graph"){
      data = matrix(sample(0:1, 400, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8,0.2)), nrow = 20)
      network = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(data, mode='undirected', diag = F)

      # plot simple graph of 5 points
      plot(network, layout = layout.circle, main = "circle")
    } else {
      plot(1:5)
    }
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was missing the renderPlot function with the network graph.  The rest worked because I had it